# PHP - determine how many bytes sent over http

Tags: php, byte, file-transfer

Is it possible in PHP to get a count of the number of bytes transmitted to the client? For example, if I'm outputting a 10 MB file, is there a way to find out if all 10 MB were sent to the client, or to see if the client interrupted the transfer partway? I know Apache will log this afterwards, but I'd like to access the data in PHP.

Comment: you want to make a progressbar or something like that?

Comment: i just wanted to mark files as completely downloaded, then remove them from a list.  the problem was file_get_contents(), it doesn't catch the user interruption.  if you use fread() and loop through, you can catch it, and then use ftell() to figure out roughly how many bytes were sent.

(sorry for posting the question when i ended up figuring it out on my own)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ignore_user_abort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and [`connection_abort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) function.

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I ended up doing (thanks Gumbo):

```
ignore_user_abort(true);

$handle = fopen($file_path, 'r');
while ( ! feof($handle)) {
    echo fread($handle, 4096);
    if (connection_aborted()) {
        $transfer_success = false;
        $bytes_transferred = ftell($handle);
        break;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```