# PHP HTTP Raw I/O Tracking on Apache

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to find a way to measure bytes transferred in or out of a web application built on php+apache. One problem is that all I/O is done by a native PHP extension, which is passed a handle to one of the [built-in streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php): php://input or php://output.

I have examined the following alternatives:

1.) ftell on stream wrapper
After encountering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507985/php-determine-how-many-bytes-sent-over-http), my first intuition was to try using ftell on the stream wrapper handle after the I/O operation; roughly:

```
$hOutput = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
extensionDoOutput($hOutput);
$iBytesTransferred = ftell($hOutput);
```

This seems to work for the input wrapper, but not the output (which always returns zero from ftell).

2.) Attach stream filter
A non-modifying stream filter would seem like a reasonable way to count bytes passing through. However, the documentation seems [a bit lacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-bucket-make-writeable.php) and I haven't found a way to get at lengths without doing the iterate+copy pattern as in the example:

```
class test_filter extends php_user_filter {
  public static $iTotalBytes = 0;

  function filter(&$in, &$out, &$consumed, $closing) {
    while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
      $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
      stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
    }
    test_filter::$iTotalBytes += $consumed;
    return PSFS_PASS_ON;
  }
}

stream_filter_register("test", "test_filter")
    or die("Failed to register filter");

$f = fopen("php://output", "wb");

stream_filter_append($f, "test");

// do i/o
```

Unfortunately this seems to impose a significant reduction in throughput (>50%) as the data is copied in and out of the extension.

3.) Implement stream wrapper
A custom stream wrapper could be used to wrap the other stream and accumulate bytes read/written:

```
class wrapper {
    var $position;

    var $handle;

    function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path)
    {
        $this->position = 0;
...
        $this->handle = fopen($opened_path, $mode);
        return $this->handle != false;
    }

    function stream_read($count)
    {
        $ret = fread($this->handle, $count);
        $this->position += strlen($ret);
        return $ret;
    }

    function stream_write($data)
    {
        $written = fwrite($this->handle, $data);
        $this->position += $written;
        return $written;
    }

    function stream_tell()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    function stream_eof()
    {
        return feof($this->handle);
    }
...
}

stream_wrapper_register("test", "wrapper")
    or die("Failed to register protocol");

$hOutput = fopen('test://output', 'wb');
extensionDoOutput($hOutput);
$iBytesTransferred = ftell($hOutput);
```

Again, this imposes a reduction in throughput (~20% on output, greater on input)

4.) Output buffering with callback
A callback can be provided with [ob_start](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to be called as chunks of output are flushed.

```
$totalBytes = 0;

function cb($strBuffer) {
   global $totalBytes;
   $totalBytes += strlen($strBuffer);
   return $strBuffer;
}

$f = fopen("php://output", "wb");

ob_start('cb', 16384);
// do output...
fclose($f);
ob_end_flush();
```

Again, this works but imposes a certain throughput performance penalty (~25%) due to buffering.

---

Option #1 was forgone because it does not appear to work for output. Of the remaining three, all work functionally but affect throughput negatively due to buffer/copy mechanisms.

Is there something instrinsic to PHP (or the apache server extensions) that I can use to do this gracefully, or will I need to bite the bullet on performance? I welcome any ideas on how this might be accomplished.
(note: if possible I am interested in a PHP application-level solution... not an apache module)

Comment: What is the name of the *"native PHP extension"* you write about in your question?

Comment: I suggest you stick with `ftell` for the input if it works - you're not likely to find anything better, certainly anything that works for both  input and output. I would be interested to see a) whether output buffering works when writing to the `php://output` stream (probably should), and b) how much of a performance decrease there is from buffering the whole thing, then doing `$bytesOut = ob_get_length(); ob_end_flush();` - I sort of suspect this will damage performance heavily, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: @hakre: It's a custom extension. Not publicly available, but also not a candidate for modification (which is why I'm asking at this level). I have examined the interface and there is not a way to get this information from the extension.

Comment: @DaveRandom: thanks for the thoughts. I agree on the input.
a.) it does
b.) it is not always feasible for this application to buffer the entire output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick to the output buffer callback you can just return `FALSE` to pass through:

```
class OutputMetricBuffer
{
    private $length;
    public function __construct()
    {
        ob_start(array($this, 'callback'));
    }
    public function callback($str)
    {
        $this->length += strlen($str);
        return FALSE;
    }
    public function getLength()
    {
        ob_flush();
        return $this->length;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$metric = new OutputMetricBuffer;

# ... output ...

$length = $metric->getLength();
```

The reasons to use the output buffer callback is because it's more lightweight than a filter which needs to consume all buckets and copy them over. So it's more work.

I implemented the callback inside a class so it has it's own private `length` variable to count up with.

You can just create a global function as well and use a global variable, however another tweak might be to access it via `$GLOBALS` instead of the `global` keyword so PHP does not need to import the global variable into the local symbol table and back. But I'm not really sure if it makes a difference, just another point which could play a role.

Anyway I don't know as well if returning `FALSE` instead of `$str` will make it faster, just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As bizarre as this is, using the `STDOUT` constant instead of the result of `fopen('php://output')` makes `ftell()` work correctly.

```
$stream = fopen('php://output','w');
fwrite($stream, "This is some data\n");
fwrite($stream, ftell($stream));
// Output:
// This is some data
// 0
```

However:

```
fwrite(STDOUT, "This is some data\n");
fwrite(STDOUT, ftell(STDOUT));
// Output:
// This is some data
// 17
```

Tested PHP/5.2.17 (win32)

**EDIT** actually, is that working correctly, or should it be `18`? I never use `ftell()` so I'm not 100% sure either way...

**ANOTHER EDIT**

See whether this suits you:

```
$bytesOutput = 0;

function output_counter ($str) {
  $GLOBALS['bytesOutput'] += strlen($str);
  return $str;
}
ob_start('output_counter');

$stream = fopen('php://output','w');
fwrite($stream, "This is some data\n");

var_dump($bytesOutput);
```

Comment: Interesting observation. I'll experiment with passing that handle to the extension instead.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure STDOUT is available in non-CLI context.

Comment: No you are right, it doesn't exist (just checked) - ahh well, nevermind. I will keep playing with it to see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Adam I don't have to discuss it fully now, but see if the code in my recent edit helps (it may not)

Comment: this looks roughly equivalent to approach #4 in my question. It works but slows things down a bit.

Comment: @Adam Sorry, I totally missed #4 in your question and yes this is pretty much identical - no worries, I will keep playing when I get time (not now, dinner time :-D)